# Error org.dom4j.DocumentException: Error on line 1 of document : Premature end of file. Nested exception: Premature end of file

Tags: java, service, web, dom4j

I get this error while testing Java Web Service. Here is exception where I use import DocumentException:

```
            Element root = null;
        SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
        Document document;

        try {
            document = reader.read(new java.io.StringReader(outputXml));
        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            Output.setErrorCode("100");
            Output.setErrorText("Greska " + e);
            return Output;
        }
```

I have no basic idea what happened.. Thanks in advance.

update:

```
String outputXml = getHTML(poziv);
private String getHTML(String urlToRead) {
URL url;
HttpURLConnection conn;
    BufferedReader rd;
    String line;
    String result = "";
    try {
        url = new URL(urlToRead);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");
        rd = 
new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            result += line;
        }
        rd.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Also, I have one basic web.xml, but not sure if it is connected with the error.

Comment: Could you add the XML file to your post?

Comment: You are missing some end tag in the xml